# .htaccess issue for a subdomain site in Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, subdomain

I have created a Magento site for my main domain. Now I need to add one more store to my subdomain. I created a website, store, and store view. Then I added secure and insecure base URLs. After that I edited my .htaccess file which was in my root folder and it already contained the code for some stores which are hosted in the main domain, and here I need to create a subdomain. I used the below code in the .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=website_code
SetEnvIf Host www\.abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=website_code
SetEnvIf Host ^abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Still the sub domain cannot connect to Magento... why is it so? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the environment variable MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE are correctly set and you can access them via PHP. You should see them in a file outputting [phpinfo()](http://www.php.net/phpinfo). If they are not set it is possible that your server environment cannot handle environmental variables. The `mod_env` module should be activated on your server, else your solution will not work.

---

But you dont need to use the environment variables:

Which store will be launched from Magento is defined in the index.php in the root directory. At the end of the file you will find the following code:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

change this to:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'maindomain.com':
  case 'www.maindomain.com':
    $mageRunCode = 'firstsite';
    $mageRunType = 'website';
  break;
  case 'subdomain.maindomain.com':
    $mageRunCode = 'secondsite';
    $mageRunType = 'website';
  break;
}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

just change the `$mageRunCode` and desired `$mageRunType` with your actual values and it should work!

Comment: 'mod_env' is enabled in my server, I checked it.

Comment: do you see the variables in the php_info() output? If yes than your mod_env setup is correct and it should work without modifying the index.php. I dont know another solution.